# How to solve Laravel select queries conflicting with the $appends property on models?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a situation where I need a specific attribute accessor appended to one of my models automatically:

```
class Mission extends Eloquent {  
    protected $appends = ['launch_date_time'];

    public function getLaunchDateTimeAttribute() {
        return ($this->attributes['launch_approximate'] == null) ? $this->attributes['launch_exact'] : $this->attributes['launch_approximate'];
    }
}
```

As you can see, this `launch_date_time` property is dependent on two other fields of my model that are actually in my database.

However, I now want to perform a query where only a certain number of fields are returned, as this is going to be sent over AJAX multiple times and I would rather use as few resources as possible:

```
// AJAX GET
// missions/all
public function all() {
    $allMissions = Mission::with('featuredImage')->get(['mission_id', 'name', 'featured_image']);
    return Response::json($allMissions);
}
```

The issue here is that I no longer need the `launch_date_time` attribute, so I have excluded it, **in doing so, my AJAX request does not work successfully:

```
Undefined index: launch_approximate on line 78 of H:\myproj\app\models\Mission.php
```

This is clearly because my model is attempting to append `launch_date_time`, of which `launch_approximate` is a dependency of. If I include all the required dependencies, all of them any my attribute that I want to append appear:

```
$allMissions = Mission::with('featuredImage')->get(['mission_id', 'name', 'featured_image', 'launch_approximate', 'launch_exact', 'launch_date_time']);
```

This is undesirable. Is there a solution where I can keep both setups?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not working is because you are not retrieving the required fields from the database in the `get` method on your query. That is why you can't access `launch_exact` and `launch_approximate` because they are not set in the instance of your model.

So to make it work like you want. You would have to check if `launch_exact` and `launch_approximate` are set before you access them.

```
public function getLaunchDateTimeAttribute() {
    if(isset($this->attributes['launch_approximate']) && $this->attributes['launch_exact']) {
        return ($this->attributes['launch_approximate'] == null) ? $this->attributes['launch_exact'] : $this->attributes['launch_approximate'];
    } 

    return null;
}
```

You can also set a whitelist with the `$visible` property and a black list with `$hidden` inside your model to not show certain attributes when outputing to json or a array take a look at the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json